# How to fulfill 2d arrays?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

First task: I have to make an unknown sized matrix.
Second task: Which contains growing numbers from zero to until my matrix ends. I can't do the second part of the task.

```
     {
Console.WriteLine(" Type the row size into the Console ");
   int row =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(" Type the column size into the Console ");
   int column = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] matrix = new int[row, column];
     for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
       for (int x = 0; x < column; x++)
  {
       Console.Write(matrix[i,x]);
  }
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'd like to get something like this:
Type the row size into the Console:
2
Type the column size into the Console:
2

output : 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should fill the matrix inside the loops before displaying it for that you can do: `int k = 0; ... matrix[i,x] = k++;` then display it

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is unassigned. You tell the computer to write matrix[0,0], matrix[0,1], etc. But those elements have no values.

Try:

matrix[i,x]=...; //Somevalue
Console.write(matrix[i,x]);

Later edit: in the desired output, you mention values 0, 1, 2,... which come from iterating over an array. However, you have a matrix. Is there something more in your problem?

Comment: This was my first thoughts but if I do this solution the matrix will have only one value

Comment: Each element of the matrix will have one value. The entire matrix will have row*col values.

Comment: It is. You have to pick your own values for the matrix' elements. Replace 10 with something that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate loops here. One would fill the 2D array with sequential integers. The other will display the array content. You have only written the second loop in your code. Write this loop before your second loop.

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < column; x++)
  {
       matrix[i,x] = k++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stack Overflow, mate :D

What you did in line:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[row, column];
```

You declared a peculiar to C# multidimensional array (google jagged arrays for different type of matrices in C#) and initialized it with default values for `int` data type, that is 0. So now you've got an arrays with zeros.

You can index into array with syntax like `matrix[i,x]` where `i` refers to row and `x` refers to column. Now you need to assign values to fields in the array.

```
matrix[i,x] = i + x;
```

This is not solution to your problem, but as this is clearly some homework assignment you need to think about it yourself.

Try to think what do those indexing values mean (`i` and `x`) - try imagining the matrix (draw it!) and see what happens when you increment `i`? Or `x`? In which direction you move in the matrix you drew?

Then think how does incrementing index values can help you traverse whole array. Ok! Now you know how to traverse whole array visiting each field once, think how to make all the values monotonically increasing by one.

**Hint**: use some counter variable OR think about combination of `i` and `x` values that would give you the same effect (they are not some magical things, but just ordinary variables you can use that have different values on each iteration).

I wish you good luck with your assignment! By the way, I think that question like this has been asked like a million times, you would get result much quicker just googling it.

Comment: Thanks for helping I will keep your tips!